# how to remove one item from arrayList

Tags: java, android

Let's pretend I have

```
List<Integer> mIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
mIds.add(0,10);
mIds.add(1,10);
mIds.add(2,10);
```

I want to remove only one item of the `listview` but when I do this it removes all the items from the `ArrayList`. Do you know why?

```
int j=-1;
for (int i=0; i < mIds.size(); i++){
     if (mIds.get(i) == modifier.getId()){
         j=i;
         break;
     }
}
if (j != -1){
    mIds.remove(j);
}
```

**EDIT: Sorry guys my problem was another; but I thought it is related on of removing list items. Thanks to everyone for the help**

Comment: How about debugging your code?

Comment: what exception you faced write first.

Comment: there is no exception, it removes all items of arrays list

Comment: Tested it and seems there's no problem at all. In the end, the List has 2 elements with value 10.

Comment: I don't know how this can remove all the items or your list. Either it removes one or zero, but not all.

Comment: Code works absolutely fine. How you concluded that your list is becoming empty?

Comment: This code you will never get empty `List.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider the value to remove element from the `List`, all element in the `List` will remove since all element has same value.

Consider the `index` to remove element

So just use

```
 List<Integer> mIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 mIds.add(0,10);
 mIds.add(1,10); // *
 mIds.add(2,10);

 mIds.remove(1); // 1 is index
```

Now `*` element will remove.

For your case

```
mIds.remove(modifier.getId());
```

Now consider your code.

```
    List<Integer> mIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    mIds.add(0,10);
    mIds.add(1,10);
    mIds.add(2, 10);

    int j=-1;
    for (int i=0; i < mIds.size(); i++){
        if (mIds.get(i) == 10){ // 0th element is 10
            j=i; //then j=0
            break; // breaks the for loop
        }
    }
    if (j != -1){ // j=0 and this is true
        mIds.remove(j); // now 0th element will remove
    }
```

So your code is works fine. There is no way to remove all element since this `remove()` runs out side a loop, So definitely one or zero element will remove.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using wrong argument in remove method. In the Collection interface you have this method:

- [remove(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29)

List has also a remove method:

- [remove(int index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29)

But in this case you are removing object at some specific index.

You can try moving element using method in Collection interface:

```
mIds.remove(Integer.valueOf(j));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing up two implementations of `remove()`. One receives an `Object`, the other an `int`, ant the behavior is distinct on each case.

Answer (score 0):

```
List_Of_Array.remove(index);
```

then update it

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

mIds.remove(2) will remove the element on index 2.

mIds.remove(Integer.valueOf(10)) will remove the first occurrence, if present. In this case it is present.

Comment: `mIds.remove(10)` will throw an exception. `mIds.remove(Integer.valueOf(10))` will remove the first occurence.